# LaTeX listing package coloring part of keyword only

Tags: colors, latex, keyword

For some reason when i compile my master, only part of keywords in my listings are colored. It's almost like it's combining keywords and only coloring the parts that are the same in the keyword. See the picture below. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

for example in the keyword "string", it only colors the "ing" part blue. And in "class" it only colors the part "ass".

I am using the following in my preamble:

```
\lstset{
backgroundcolor=\color{white},
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
breakatwhitespace=true,
 breaklines=true,
 commentstyle=\color{green},
 frame=single,
 keywordstyle=\color{blue},
 language=[Sharp]{C},
 numbers=left,
% morecomment = [l]{//}, 
% morecomment = [l]{///},
% morecomment = [s]{/*}{*/},
% morestring=[b]", 
 sensitive = true,
 showstringspaces=false,
 otherkeywords = {
 abstract, as, base, bool,
 break, byte, case, catch,
 char, byte, class, const,
 continue, decimal, default, delegate,
 do, double, else, enum,
 event, explicit, extern, false,
 finally, fixed, float, for,
 foreach, goto, if, implicit,
 in, int, interface,
 internal, is, lock, long,
 namespace, new, null, object,
 operator, out, override,
 params, private, protected, public,
 readonly, ref, return, sbyte,
 sealed, short, sizeof, stackalloc,
 static, string, struct, switch,
 this, throw, true, try,
 typeof, uint, ulong, unchecked,
 unsafe, ushort, using, virtual,
 void, volatile, while
 }
}
```

Comment: This post has been flagged for migration to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), you may get an answer more quickly there. Also, if you post a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it gets easier to help you.

Comment: I had the same problem, apparently the package gets confused when there's a keyword inside another keyword. So your "strings" are getting half colored because "in" is contained within "strINgs". I don't have a solution though, except for deleting "in" from the keyword list